# How to create a userprofile form without using the django admin?

Tags: django

I want to create a template which deals with user log in , and user profile creation . I do not want to use the django-admin . So how do I manage it ? The django documentation doesn't really talk much about doing user login without django-admin.

Answer (score 2):

As far as user profile creation is concerned, it's best to make a post_save signal callback for the User model which creates the profile if it does not exist.. for example:

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UserProfile(models.Model)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    # ... etc, your user-profile stuff here

def user_save_callback(sender, **kwargs):
    user = kwargs['instance']
    user_profile, user_profile_created = UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=user)

post_save.connect(user_save_callback, sender=User)
```

Don't forget to add `AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE='my_app.my_user_profile_model'` to your settings.py

Then, you can access the profile in your views with `request.user.get_profile()` after the user has been created.

Comment: A very basic template code as to how to deal with the username and password would be very helpful

Comment: The django documentation provides a nice login template to help you get started, check it out [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#django.contrib.auth.views.login)

Answer (score 0):

`django.contrib.auth.views.login` accepts `template_name` argument. You can see sample template in [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#django.contrib.auth.views.login).

Answer (score 0):

for login see the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#how-to-log-a-user-in) for creating your own view or you can use the built in views with your own template.

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
                       (r'^login/$', 
                        'django.contrib.auth.views.login', 
                        {'template_name': 'accounts/login.html'}),

                       (r'^logout/$', 
                        'django.contrib.auth.views.logout', 
                        {'template_name': 'accounts/logged_out.html'}),
```

for sign up you could use [django registration](https://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-registration)

Answer (score 0):

What? There's [a whole page](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/auth/) on authentication which hardly mentions the admin site.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
```

Use `create_user(username,email,password)` method for creating a user without admin.

```
user=User.objects.create_user(username,email,password)
user.save()
```